# Correct interpretation of logic

Tags: logic

I answered the following question and would like to know if my answer is correct.

Question:

Under what conditions will the statements p1, p2, p3 and p4 be executed?

```
if (a<0) { p1 } else if (b!=0) { p2 }
else if (a==b) { p3 } else if (a==0) { p4 }
```

NB: the question was formatted in exactly the same way as that above.

My answer:

p1 executed if `a < 0`.

p2 executed if `a >= 0 and b != 0`.

p3 executed if `a >= 0, b == 0 and a == b` - that is, if `a and b are both equal to 0`.

p4 is never executed, since it is not possible that both `a == 0 and a < b == 0` can hold at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right. but even if `a == 0` then either b is 0 or not.

If b is 0 then you go and execute p3 while if b is not 0 then you execute p2. Hence p4 is never executed.